# How to programmatically pop a view controller and present a new one

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

What I am trying to do is present a viewController and when the user touches a button I want to call popViewController and then present a different viewController.  But I cannot figure out how to do it.

Some of the things I have tried are call pop and then immediately call present, call present after a delay, pup the pop with a completion block and then in the completion block call present, as well as other ideas.

I think I am over complicating the whole thing, i believe their should be an easy way to do this.

Thanks for any help with this.

CLARIFICATION:

I do this on a touch:

```
        if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Listing", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as? ListingViewController
    {
        vc.listing = listing
        vc.editListing = forEdit
        vc.title = " "
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

From that VC when the user touches a button I do this:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

When the VC goes away I want to do something like this:

```
        if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "CreateListing", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as? NewCreateListingViewController
    {
        vc.bMakeSimiliar = makeSimiliar
        vc.listing = listing
        vc.editListing = editListing
        vc.title = " "
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Basically my user is viewing the first controller which is a listing, from the listing VC he touches a button to add a new listing, so I want to dismiss the listing view controller and present him with the create listing view controller.

When I execute the above code to present the new VC nothing happens.  I am doing this immediately after the popViewController.

Comment: You need to show relevant code. How was the view controller displayed? If presented, it needs to be dismissed, not popped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use pop to present *next* controller in stack. Pop actually navigates back from the current controller.

To perform what you're trying to achieve you need to call `navigationController.pushViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)` method.

In order to get back to some previous view controller you use:
`navigationController.popViewController(animated: Bool)`

In order to get to the root view controller you use:
`navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: Bool)`

In order to get to some specific view controller in the stack you use:
`popToViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)`

Comment: So if I call push the new VC will appear, but when the user goes back, where will it take them?   I want them to go back to VC before the previous one.

Comment: Ok, i am sorry, i said it a bit wrong.  I have already pushed the VC.  Then the user touches a button.  On the touch I want to pop the VC and present/push a new VC.  But on back from the new VC, I want to go to the one before the previous.  I will update my question.

Comment: @LilMoke check the updated answer! You're looking for `popToViewController`

Comment: No wait, I have tried that, my problem is the second view controller does not show. If I call present right after the pop the new controller does not appear.

Comment: Okay, then. Just to clarify. Your use case is: Controller A -> push Controller B, when user touches Button in Controller B, you want to show Controller C, but when Controller C is poped you want to show Controller A?

Comment: Yes, and in this discussion I think I may have realized what I am fighting with.  I am having trouble pushing B, If you look at my code above I think it is because I am trying to pop A and present B, but B is from a different storyboard.  I understand what you are saying and yes, that would work IF this was all in the same storyboard with the same NavController.

Comment: When using multiple storyboards you need to call `presentViewController` instead of push if that navigation leads to another storyboard.

Comment: If you were using segues, you could create a target storyboard reference in your storyboard, but since you're doing navigation programatically your option is to use `present` and `dismiss`.

Comment: Yes, I get it.  I will change the code and see if that works.  I think it will, thanks.